# Download list of files if they don't already exist

Tags: wget, download, options

If I have a list of URLs separated by `\n`, are there any options I can pass to `wget` to download all the URLs and save them to the current directory, but only if the files don't already exist?

Comment: Related: [Skip download if files exist in wget?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4944295/55075) at SO

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a `-nc` (`--no-clobber`) option for `wget`.

Comment: I read this _after_ writing my Bash script to check for the existence of files individually!

Answer (score 11):

From `wget --help`:

```
....
-i,  --input-file=FILE     download URLs found in local or external FILE.
....
-nc, --no-clobber          skip downloads that would download to
                           existing files.
-c,  --continue            resume getting a partially-downloaded file.
....
```

I've included `--continue` because it seemed like it might be helpful if you're trying to recover from an interrupted download, but you don't need it to answer your original question.